# Uncaught ReferenceError: downloadCSV is not defined (HTML)

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, csv, export

Hi I'm working on a feature to extract the array in CSV format. I successfully, converted my array to comma delimited.

However, I'm having an error when clicking the anchor (link) to export the csv file. Can you help me point on what is causing the error?

Thanks in advance!

[Here is a sample of the array to Comma delimited data in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFMI4.jpg)

[Error Screenshot in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaUtP.jpg)

HTML Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cs/css/styles.css" />
  <title>Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="navigation-bar">
    <div class="title">
      <a class="link" href="/">Tool</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="page-content">
    <h3 class="breadcrumbs" id="breadcrumbs">Cs</h3>
    <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">Drop .json file here to convert</div>
    <div class="display-area" id="displayarea">
      <a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "stock-data.csv" });'>Download CSV</a>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="/cs/js/dragdrop.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Code

```
    "use strict";

(function() {
  var dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");

  dropzone.ondrop = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.className = "dropzone";

    var fileInput = document.getElementById("dropzone");
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById("displayarea");

    var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    var textType = "";

    if (file.type.match(textType)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(read) {

        var json = reader.result;
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);

        var mainObj = obj.value.map(function(v, i){
          return {
            id: v.changesetId,
            author: v.author.displayName,
            createdDate: v.createdDate,
            comment: v.comment
          };
        });

        hideDropZone();
        createTable(mainObj);
        arrayToCSV(mainObj);
      }

    } else {
      // fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
      console.log("File not supported!")
    }

    reader.readAsText(file);

  }

  dropzone.ondragover = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.className = "dropzone -dragover";
  };

  dropzone.ondragleave = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.className = "dropzone";
  };

  var hideDropZone = function() {
    document.getElementById("dropzone").style.display = "none";
  }

  var arrayToCSV = function(args) {
    var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

    data = args;
    if (data == null || !data.length) {
      return null;
    }

    columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ",";
    lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || "\n";

    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

    // console.log(data);

    result = "";
    result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
    result += lineDelimiter;

    data.forEach(function(item) {
      ctr = 0;
      keys.forEach(function(key) {
        if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

        result += item[key];
        ctr++;
      });
      result += lineDelimiter;
    });
    console.log(result);
  }

  var downloadCSV = function(args) {
    var data, filename, link;
    var csv = arrayToCSV ({
      data: stockData
    });
    if (csv == null) return;

    filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

    if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
      csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,sep=,\n' + csv;
    }
    data = encodeURI(csv);

    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', data);
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.click();

    console.log(csv);
  }

  var createTable = function(data) {
    //changeset
    var changesetDisplay = document.getElementById("breadcrumbs");
    var changesetValue = document.createTextNode(" ("+data.length+")");
    changesetDisplay.appendChild(changesetValue);

    //table
    var displayArea = document.getElementById("displayarea");
    var cols = ["ID", "Author", "Created Date", "Comment"];
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.classList.add("datatable");
    var tHead = document.createElement("thead");
    tHead.classList.add("header");
    var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    tBody.classList.add("body");
    var headerRow = document.createElement("tr");

    //header
    for (var num = 0; num < cols.length; num++) {
      var headerCell = document.createElement("th");
      var headerCellValue = document.createTextNode(cols[num]);
      headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
      headerCell.appendChild(headerCellValue);
    }
    tHead.appendChild(headerRow);
    table.appendChild(tHead);

    //body
    for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
      var rowId = document.createElement("tr");

      var colId = document.createElement("td");
      var colIdValue = document.createTextNode(data[row].id);

      var colAuthor = document.createElement("td");
      var colAuthorValue = document.createTextNode(data[row].author);

      var colCreatedDate = document.createElement("td");
      var colCreatedDateValue = document.createTextNode(data[row].createdDate);

      var colComment = document.createElement("td");
      var colCommentValue = document.createTextNode(data[row].comment);

      colId.appendChild(colIdValue);
      colAuthor.appendChild(colAuthorValue);
      colCreatedDate.appendChild(colCreatedDateValue);
      colComment.appendChild(colCommentValue);

      rowId.appendChild(colId);
      rowId.appendChild(colAuthor);
      rowId.appendChild(colCreatedDate);
      rowId.appendChild(colComment);

      tBody.appendChild(rowId);
    }

    table.appendChild(tBody);
    displayArea.appendChild(table);
    console.log(table);
  };

}());
```

Comment: `downloadCSV` isn't global. If you use `onxyz`-attribute-style handlers, it needs to be (one of many reasons not to use them). See the linked question's answers.

Comment: Thanks TJ, I believe this is the 'link.click();' onxyz-attribute-style handler, right?

Comment: No, this (in the HTML): `<a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "stock-data.csv" });'>Download CSV</a>`.